# Metal kernel function not found

Tags: ios, xcode, kernel, metal, metalkit

I am trying to use Metal Performance Shaders with Core Image.

Unfortunately, the filter code is in Objective C and I am using the bridge to make it work with the Swift project.

My-Project-Bridging-Header.h

```
#import "MyCustomFilter.h"
```

MyCustomFilter.h

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

@interface MyCustomFilter : CIFilter
......
@end
```

MyCustomFilter.m

```
#import "MyCustomFilter.h"
#import "MyCustomFilterKernel.h"

.......
```

MyCustomFilterKernel.h

```
#import <CoreImage/CoreImage.h>

@interface MyCustomFilterKernel : CIImageProcessorKernel

@end
```

MyCustomFilterKernel.m

```
#import "FTWaveformScopeKernel.h"
#import "FTWaveformScopeFilter.h"

#import <Metal/Metal.h>

    ...

+ (void) initialize {
 id<MTLFunction> customFunction = [defaultLibrary newFunctionWithName:@"custom_Function"];
 if (customFunction) {
  NSError* error;
  kCustomComputePipelineState = [kDevice newComputePipelineStateWithFunction: customFunction error:&error];
  if (error) {
    NSLog(@"error loading kernel function (custom_Function): %@", error);
  } 
 } else {
     NSLog(@"kernel function (custom_Function) not found");
 }
```

CustomFunction.metal

```
    #include <metal_stdlib>
    using namespace metal;
   
    ......

    kernel void
    custom_Function(texture2d<float, access::sample>        inTexture       [[texture(0)]],
                        texture2d<float, access::write>         outTexture      [[texture(1)]],
                        volatile device atomic_uint*            columnDataRed   [[buffer(0)]],
                        volatile device atomic_uint*            columnDataGreen [[buffer(1)]],
                        volatile device atomic_uint*            columnDataBlue  [[buffer(2)]],
                        sampler                                 wrapSampler     [[sampler(0)]],
                        uint2                                   gid                       
                        [[thread_position_in_grid]])
{

........

}
```

The error I get is (with the metal view being blank/transparent):

```
kernel function (custom_Function) not found
```

I've also done:

[image]

I am dealing with Xcode 12.x. The above code compiles and runs.

### UPDATE

After that first reply, I followed the new Xcode 12 and later settings:
https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2020/10021/

1. Changed `CustomFunction.metal` in to `CustomFunction.ci.metal`
2. Added the first rule:
   [image]
3. Added the third rule:
   [image]

Now the project does not compile:

```
LLVM ERROR: Error opening 

    /Users/xxxxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxxxx-ggaphqixkeecbkewrntvhssdgnac/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxxxxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxxxxx.build/DerivedSources/CustomFunction.ci.air': No such file or directory!
    Command RuleScriptExecution failed with a nonzero exit code


RuleScriptExecution /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-ggaphqixkeecbkewrntvhssdgnac/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xxxx\ xxxx.app/CustomFunction.ci.metallib /Users/xxxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxxx-xxxx-ggaphqixkeecbkewrntvhssdgnac/Build/Intermediates.noindex/xxxx-xxxx.build/Debug-iphoneos/xxxx-xxxx.build/DerivedSources/CustomFunction.ci.air normal undefined_arch (in target 'xxxx-xxxx' from project 'xxxx-xxxx')
    cd /Users/xxxx/Desktop/xxxx-xxxx\ CustomFunction
    /bin/sh -c xcrun\ metallib\ -cikernel\ \"\$\{INPUT_FILE_PATH\}\"\ -o\ \"\$\{SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0\}\"'
'
```

These are the two lines in text:

```
xcrun metallib -cikernel "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"

xcrun metal -c -I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS -fcikernel  "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${SCRIPT_OUPUT_FILE_0}"
```

Since I had to type these looking at a screenshot, maybe I made a mistake interpreting? There is a double space after `-fcikernel`?

Comment: Given the sample code I imagine the kernel is not nested in a namespace correct? If it were you would need to qualify the name with that namespace (e.g., if you had `namespace Custom { kernel Your_name ... }`, you would need to say "Custom::[Your_name]" in `newFunctionWithName:`

Comment: Tried that and no luck. Am I missing a #include? Somehow the custom kernels arent getting seen during run time?

Comment: Maybe this kernel is written for MacOS? Won't work with iOS?

Comment: Can you please try again without `-I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS` (and without double spaces)?

Comment: I get the same error. 'No such file or directory!'

Comment: OP updated with the new error

Answer (score 1):

The Metal toolchain changed in Xcode 12. The above linker flags no longer work since the default toolchain no longer uses the `metallib` linker.

Please check out [David's talk from WWDC 2020](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10021) on how to properly set up the build system for compiling custom Core Image kernels.

Comment: Updated the OP. Still having issues.

Comment: export PATH="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents//Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/metal/macos/bin/:$PATH"
 xcrun -sdk macosx metal -c add.metal -o add.air
 xcrun -sdk macosx metallib add.air -o default.metallib

Answer (score 1):

There is indeed a typo in your script (missing T in SCRIPT_OUPUT_FILE_0)

I copied your script and got same error. Once typo was corrected, the app built successfully. The corrected script text follows...

```
xcrun metal -c -I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS -fcikernel "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"

xcrun metallib -cikernel "${INPUT_FILE_PATH}" -o "${SCRIPT_OUTPUT_FILE_0}"
```

Comment: PS - I also had to remove "-I $MTL_HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS" from the first script before the built app was able to actually recognise that the custom function existed in the metal file.